# Should I store empty tsvector values or NULL values?

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

When storing a `tsvector` value in a column, for records with no search terms, should I store an empty `tsvector` or a `NULL` value?

Does it matter?

Is there any difference in terms of performance, or storage overhead from storing empty vectors?

In other words, when updating the vector based on a value of, say, a nullable `title` column, do I need to always compute this as `to_tsvector(coalesce(title,''))` (since `to_tsvector` returns `NULL` when given a `NULL` argument) or is it enough to do `to_tsvector(title)`?

Comment: I think NULLs stored before tuples no matter if the column is tsvector or not, so probably no effect on storage space. But saving null or not is important - having column NOT NULL changes a lot

Comment: Using `coalesce()` inside `to_tsvector()` is usually the best practice when multiple column are involved. Because the concatenation operator (`||`) will yield `NULL` when either of the columns is `NULL`. I.e. if you have a `title` and a `description` column, you'll need to use `to_tsvector(coalesce(title,'')) || to_tsvector(coalesce(description,''))`. Because if you are not using `coalesce()`, the rows which have title, but not description will be "lost". -- If you have a single column, it really does not matter.

Comment: This is especially important, when you want to use [`setweight()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-PARSING-DOCUMENTS) too.

Comment: @pozs Why is it especially important with setweight? I don't doubt you, I just ran into this after adding setweight

Comment: @ColinD because there is no benefit from calling `setweight()` on a single column. It is only meaningful, when multiple columns are involved. It is also strict, so `NULL` documents will yield `NULL`. In short, you can use `setweight()` as a rule-of-thumb: you are always expected to use `coalesce()` on nullable columns/expressions with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Logic aspects of your question

First off, the semantics of SQL `NULL` is that of `UNKNOWN`, whereas some data types also have an "empty" value. Those data types include:

- `TEXT` (`''` isn't the same as `NULL::TEXT`)
- `JSON` and `JSONB` (`[]` or `{}` aren't the same as `NULL::JSON` or `NULL:JSONB`)
- `X[]` (`ARRAY[]::X[]` isn't the same as `NULL::X[]`)

There are many more, including `TSVECTOR`. The semantics of an empty collection of something is always subtly different from that of a `NULL` value, which is an `UNKNOWN` collection (often just used as an absent collection, though). The distiction manifests specifically when it comes to using operators, e.g.

- `'' || 'abc' = 'abc'` but `NULL || 'abc' IS NULL`
- `to_tsvector('cats ate rats') @@ to_tsquery('cat & rat') = true` but `NULL @@ to_tsquery('cat & rat') IS NULL`

In that sense, the decision should be foremost a logic one, not a storage one, based on this question: Will you still work with the `TSVECTOR` value of a record, even if the record doesn't have any search terms (pro empty `TSVECTOR`)? Or does the feature not apply at all to that particular record (pro `NULL` value)? For the `@@` operator, it may not be so relevant, but it definitely is for the `||` operator, and others.

The answer isn't obvious, nor is there a clear right / wrong way in general.

#### Performance aspects of your question

If this is a highly performance sensitive situation in your application (e.g. you have a lot of empty `TSVECTOR` values), then maybe, this benchmark could help you with the decision?

I ran the below benchmark on PostgreSQL 14.1 in Docker to get this result:

```
RUN 1, Statement 1: 2.91145
RUN 1, Statement 2: 1.00000 -- The fastest run is 1. The others are multiples of 1
RUN 2, Statement 1: 2.80509
RUN 2, Statement 2: 1.05232
RUN 3, Statement 1: 2.78001
RUN 3, Statement 2: 1.00202
RUN 4, Statement 1: 2.74319
RUN 4, Statement 2: 1.00524
RUN 5, Statement 1: 2.75808
RUN 5, Statement 2: 1.00045
```

- Statement 1 is `SELECT v @@ to_tsquery('cat & rat')` with `v tsvector = to_tsvector('');`
- Statement 2 is `SELECT NULL @@ to_tsquery('cat & rat')`

The fact that `NULL` is involved probably leads to a shortcut in the `@@` operator's algorithm, which produces a 2.7x performance improvement over querying an empty `TSVECTOR` in the benchmark. So, there do seem to be benefits of using `NULL` in terms of performance.

Obviously, that's just a benchmark, which doesn't necessarily reflect real-world use-cases, but it should give you a hint of a potential difference.

**Benchmark code**

For reproduction or adaptations, [here's a benchmark, based on this technique](https://www.jooq.org/benchmark).

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  v_ts TIMESTAMP;
  v_repeat CONSTANT INT := 10000;
  rec RECORD;
  run INT[];
  stmt INT[];
  elapsed DECIMAL[];
  min_elapsed DECIMAL;
  i INT := 1;

  -- Store the vector in a local variable to avoid re-computing it in the benchmark
  v tsvector = to_tsvector('');
BEGIN

  -- Repeat the whole benchmark several times to avoid warmup penalty
  FOR r IN 1..5 LOOP
    v_ts := clock_timestamp();

    FOR i IN 1..v_repeat LOOP
      FOR rec IN (
        -- Statement 1
        SELECT v @@ to_tsquery('cat & rat')
      ) LOOP
        NULL;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    run[i] := r;
    stmt[i] := 1;
    elapsed[i] := (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CAST(clock_timestamp() AS TIMESTAMP)) 
                 - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM v_ts));
    i := i + 1;
    v_ts := clock_timestamp();

    FOR i IN 1..v_repeat LOOP
      FOR rec IN (
        -- Statement 2
        SELECT NULL @@ to_tsquery('cat & rat') 
      ) LOOP
        NULL;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    run[i] := r;
    stmt[i] := 2;
    elapsed[i] := (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CAST(clock_timestamp() AS TIMESTAMP))
                 - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM v_ts));
    i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;

  SELECT min(t.elapsed)
  INTO min_elapsed
  FROM unnest(elapsed) AS t(elapsed);

  FOR i IN 1..array_length(run, 1) LOOP
    RAISE INFO 'RUN %, Statement %: %', run[i], stmt[i], 
      CAST(elapsed[i] / min_elapsed AS DECIMAL(10, 5));
  END LOOP;
END$$;
```